# D3js attribute : why passing function as unique argument fail?

Tags: d3.js

I want to move from well established css styles section and use of classes :

```
<style>
land  { fill:grey; }
focus { fill:yellow; }
</style>

svg.
  ...      // some stuff here
  .attr("class","focus");
```

...to pure js variables :

```
var land = { 'fill':'grey' };
var focus= { 'fill':'yellow'};
```

I observe the following...

#### Conclusion

Passing 2 arguments, with the 2nd a function (1) and or one argument as a variable (2) work perfectly :

```
 .attr("class", function(d){ if(){...}else{...} })  // (1) works

 .attr(land)  // (2) works
```

but this exact same function in (1) **FAILS** when I pass it as a  single argument function (3) :

```
 .attr(function(){ return land; }) // fails. Expected to return variable  `land`, as for (2).
```

**Any idea if this is an intended d3js behavior ? What do I do wrong ? And, possibly, how to make it work.**

Comment: I'd be interested to see a fiddle or otherwise with this in action. In case 2, I don't understand precisely how that should work... what attribute is being set? The 'fill' attribute of the element?  It seems like it should be "attr( 'style', land)"

Comment: In d3 you can set style via `attr('fill', '#CCC')` or by passing objects `attr({fill:'#CCC'})`. It's convenient because you can put something longer`attr({fill:'#CCC',stroke:'2px',stroke-color:'#F00'})`. Next step is to use variables: `var css={fill:'#CCC'}; svg.append("circle").attr(css)....`

Comment: My code is (crashing) [there](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/2_zoom/index.html), line 55.

Comment: @cmonkey: Ok, I think I misunderstood your remark. I now replaced the `...` by the fragment's code so it's more readable.

Comment: Using https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#content as a reference. It doesn't clearly indicate to me what should happen if an object is passed as the only parameter. What behavior is seen if you use attr("style", "fill:grey" )? The reference of '.style( myvar )' isn't clear as I'm unsure what myvar represents.

Comment: I think I get it.  `d` is not passed when there is just one attribute. It cannot be done that way. I must first conditionally tag the elements, then later on append the style using the tags and my css variables.

Comment: `.style({"fill":"grey"})` and  `.style(land)` both works. trouble arise when  I use soemthing such `style(function(){...})` or `attr(function(){...})`. Functions, with or without d, cannot be passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrate from css styles to pure js as follow.

Your former css:

```
<style>
land  { fill:grey; }
focus { fill:yellow; }
</style>
```

...resulting js variables :

```
var land = "fill:grey" ;                        // no {}
var focus= "fill:yellow, stroke-color: #F00";   // , or ; should be ok.
```

...and d3js :

```
 ...
 .attr("style", function(){return land}) // this is the way, together with no {} !
```